# Large Scale NAT maximum concurrent connections issue

Tags: networking, nat

When I open Google Maps on a client PC that is behind a Large Scale NAT (LSN, Carrier grade NAT) the number of concurrent connections is limited to 15.

Do you have any solutions how to enable more connections when behind an LSN(CGN)?

[image: How Google Maps looks with only 15 connections]

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't aware that these LSN's were being rolled out to the public yet. What a disappointment.

Anyhow, Google Maps already tries to get around any concurrent request boundaries by splitting its map view over dozens and dozens of subdomains, as most browsers will only open a limited number of connections to a single domain.

If this is being controlled at a large NAT level, I doubt that there is anything you can do except submit a complaint to your ISP.

Comment: Google Maps works fine over IPv6.  Lose that NAT.

Comment: In large scale NAT, the connection limit is _per shared IP_, so any given customer can only have X number of simultaneous connections open to _anywhere_ at once. If someone uses UDP-based protocols, or has several devices using the same connection, then they could hit that limit very quickly. And some ISPs set the limit rather low, so as to further conserve IPv4 addresses, and/or reduce load on their gateway devices.